# "Extra data" error when converting a string to a JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert the below string to a JSON object using `json.loads`.

> "Error":"Execution failed on sql '`SELECT * FROM tablename`': ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Query timeout expired (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')"

but I'm getting the below error:

> JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 8 (char 7)

How do we convert the above string to a JSON object?

Comment: It's not JSON. A JSON object needs `{}` around it.

Comment: The string is not really even close to json. You will need to split it and reassemble it into a dictionary then dump.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. JSON is a text-based serialization format. It is unclear 1) what the result you need is 2) how that result is supposed to come from a string which seems to not be valid JSON (although, you say you want to *convert* to JSON, I think you mean you want to *deserialize the srtring*, which should be JSON encoded, into a *Python dictionary object*

Comment: Convert **to** JSON: `dumps()`. Convert **from** JSON: `loads()`

Comment: You need the curly braces at both ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap curly braces around it to get valid JSON syntax for an object.

```
result = json.loads('{' + bad_json + '}')
```